# Do you gain AP when using an ADA Refactor or Jarvis Virus?

Tags: ingress

I have yet to get either an ADA Refactor or Jarvis Virus but I am curious about their use.

If an enemy portal has Links/Fields attached and you flip it with a Refactor/Virus, do you gain AP for taking down the Links/Fields?

Comment: Be sure to check my answer if you were curious about hidden mechanics behind Viruses! :)

Answer (score 20):

No, you won't get any AP from using a virus/refactor on a portal. All of the attached Links and Fields will be destroyed, but no AP will be gained: these items are already powerful as they are, since you become the owner of the portal along with *every Mod* attached to it.

Comment: Does it flip the resonators or destroy them?

Comment: Resonators are not destroyed.  Also, using the virus costs a whole lot of XM.

Comment: 1000 XM per portal level

Answer (score 9):

You won't get any AP for flipping a portal, even though all the links and fields get destroyed.

The portal, as it was, will only change it's owner to either **you** (if it was an enemy portal) or to `__ADA__` or `__Jarvis__`, depending on what your and the portal's faction is.

This is the result of using the Jarvis virus by a resistance agent on a resistance portal.
[image: __Jarvis__ed portal]

- Flipping a portal means that **ALL** resonators and mods will **change** the owner

  - note: the comm message will say "user xy destroyed a resonator",
    however, there **WON'T** be an associated deploy or capture event (this technique is used to somewhat confuse Guardian hunters)
- The Capture date will change to the day the portal was flipped and the day counter will reset.
- The maximum of 1xL8,L7,.. resonators or 2 mods per agent don't apply for the flipping and also if you are level 5, you can flip a portal with L8 resonator.
  **!!** However, if the limits are exceeded you **won't** be able to deploy **ANY** additional resonators.
- The cost to flip a portal is 1000 XM per portal's level.
- Using the Jarvis or ADA by the same faction agent is useful if you want to get rid of blocking links.
  *note that you can't use the Jarvis virus on a green portal and ADA on a resistance portal in order to do so.
- There is 1 hour cooldown, where the portal won't get flipped after using a Virus, but you will still **lose** your Virus if you try to do so! Also the portal will not tell you if it is protected or not beforehand.

Youtube videos of Viruses in action:

[Ingress Jarvis virus effects on a linked portal.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZiqCU_isF8)
[Jarvis virus used by a resistance agent.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zw8PeJ_wbn0)